# Jest - Mock both class constructor and method

Tags: javascript, class, methods, constructor, jestjs

I'm having struggles with Jest to mock my class constructor and method at the same time.

My class looks like this, and is in a file where multiple classes exist:

```
export class ClassName {

constructor() {
// some code
}

public myMethod() {
// some code
}
}
```

In my Jest test file, I'm doing:

```
jest.mock('<path_to_my_class>', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('<path_to_my_class>'),
    ClassName : {
        default: jest.fn( function () {
            return {
                // some code
            }
        }),
        myMethod: jest.fn(async () => {
            return { // some code }
        })
    },
Class2_Name: {
// Same kind of format
}

}));
```

In my test I get a "TypeError: MyClass is not a constructor" error.

I tried a lot of different syntaxes, but I never manage to mock both class constructor and methods. Class is recognized as having a constructor if I return a function in the mock. But in this case, the class method mock doesnt work anymore.

Thank you

Comment: The constructor isn't the "default export" of a class. You need to return a function that returns an object with a callable myMethod property. Read e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks

Comment: I tried that, but then I get the "... is not a constructor" error. Not able to find any answer I used "jest.spyOn(...)" inside each test.